# nodejs - mongodb $lte and $gte not working with $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get record by price range but the query is working fine in shell but not in nodejs. Here is query:

```
db.model.aggregate([            
           { $match: { make_id: make_id } },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'variants',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'model_id',
                    as: 'variant_list'
                }
            }, 
            { 
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$variant_list',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false                                
                } 
            },
            {$match: {status:1, $and:[{'variant_list.price': {$lte:Number(max_price)}}]}},              
            {$project: { make_id: 1, model_name: 1, variant_list: '$variant_list'}} 
        ])
```

I have checked the price in database. it is stored like `NumberInt(300000)` and in my query i have parsed in integer type like => `max_price` to `Number(max_price)`.

and it gives me all record which are less than and equal to `300000` but it also gives the record which are less than `400000`.

But If i'm not using `aggregate framework` then it is giving me perfect result:

```
db.model.find({status:1, $and:[{'variant_list.price': {$lte:Number(max_price)}}]})
```

I dont know why `$lte` not working perfectly with `aggregate` and `$lookup`.

Please Help!!

**Updated Sample Collection and Documents**

> MakeId = a123;

```
Models:
-----------------------------
mid  |  makeid  |   model   |
-----------------------------
m1   |  a123    |  MDLi1    |
m2   |  a123    |  MDLi2    |
m3   |  a123    |  MDLi3    |
m4   |  a123    |  MDLi4    |
m5   |  a123    |  MDLi5    |
-----------------------------

Variants:
----------------------------------------
vid |  modelid  |  variants |  price   |
----------------------------------------
v1   |    m1    |  VARi1    |  150000  |
v2   |    m1    |  VARi2    |  250000  |
v3   |    m1    |  VARi3    |  300000  |
v4   |    m1    |  VARi4    |  350000  |
v5   |    m1    |  VARi5    |  380000  |
v6   |    m2    |  VARi6    |  250000  |
v7   |    m2    |  VARi7    |  280000  |
v8   |    m2    |  VARi8    |  380000  |
v9   |    m2    |  VARi9    |  400000  |
v10  |    m2    |  VARi10   |  450000  |
----------------------------------------
```

I need to get model detail and variants list by variant price like price range should be `between 0 to 300000`
My Desire result is :

```
{
"data": [
            {
                "makeid": "a123",
                "modelid": "m1",
                "variant_list": [
                    {
                        "variant_id": "v1",
                        "variant_name": "VARi1",
                        "price": 150000                     
                    },
                    {
                        "variant_id": "v2",
                        "variant_name": "VARi2",
                        "price": 250000                     
                    },
                    {
                        "variant_id": "v3",
                        "variant_name": "VARi3",
                        "price": 300000                     
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "makeid": "a123",
                "modelid": "m2",
                "variant_list": [
                    {
                        "variant_id": "v6",
                        "variant_name": "VARi6",
                        "price": 250000                     
                    },
                    {
                        "variant_id": "v7",
                        "variant_name": "VARi7",
                        "price": 280000                     
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: try to move `$unwind` before `$match`

Comment: already tried that.. but same result..

Comment: It would be great if you can update post to include sample documents which when run against your query can demonstrate the behavior.

Comment: @Veeram - I have updated my Question with some sample collection and document. and Please remember one thing that same query is giving me perfect result in `mongo shell` but not when i run this query in `Nodejs+Mongoose`